# Is Qt Visual Studio add-in a subset of Qt Visual Studio integration?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

Qt software recently released Qt Visual Studio Add-in. Does anybody know, is it a subset of Visual Studio Integration, or is there included something new? Anyone tried both?

Answer (score 0):

It is a full replacement.

There is no need to use the (commercial) Visual Studio Integration.

I highly recommend switching to the new Qt Visual Studio Add-in, which finally is available as version 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

Full replacement.

The only difference I noticed was that the Qt Designer opens in a new Window for the Open Source (LGPL/GPL) version. In a commercial license version the Qt Designer should be completely integrated.

Answer (score 0):

It's a replacement, but a bit different. (It knows about precompiled headers! Finally!)